# XPath select parent element only if child element exists

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, parent-child

```
<element_1> 
    <element_2>Text</element_2> 
    <element_3> 
        <element_4> 
            <element_5>Test Text</element_5> 
        </element_4> 
        <element_4> 
        </element_4> 
    </element_3> 
    <element_6> 
        <element_7> 
            <element_8>0</element_8>
```

How would I write xpath to find all instances of element_4 that contain an instance of element_5

**Context**

URL: https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_KOTHLPCG_1a1_w?node=565108&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-6&pf_rd_r=PASRJV57NJ97XPYZW0GS&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1e1598d2-28c3-4a64-91af-254d7a033ada&pf_rd_i=541966\

I am using selenium and I am trying grab the name of only the laptops that are on sale. The laptops that are on sale have an old price that is written with a strike through which is written underneath its current price. I want the names of only the laptops that have that strike through price in their listing.

Very new to Selenium and Xpath so I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete, this will select laptop names on sale (works for all pages, featured items on page 1 excluded):

```
//span[@data-a-strike="true" or contains(@class,"text-strike")][.//text()]/preceding::h2[@class][1]
```

Comment: You are a god among men. Thank you so much it would've taken me days to figure this out.